# Emulator not running my app on Eclipse.. why?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator, galaxy

I want to emulate a Galaxy Note to test my application.
I use 1280 x 800 screen size with 320 Abstracted LCD Density, android 4.0.3,
Android Virtual Machine in Eclipse.
So it is like a Note device...

My problem is when i ran my app, it is not running on the Note emulator, it is just starts a NEW one, its like its not compatible with it, but it is very strange because my apps build target is 2.3, so it should be run on android 4.0.3

What is the problem ?
Is there any better way to text in Galaxy Note ?
(I dont have the device and cannot borrow one...)

Thanks,
Adam

Comment: it starts a new what? Emulator?

Comment: For me also this part of your question is not clear: `it is not running on the Note emulator, it is just starts a NEW one, its like its not compatible with it`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check you "run configurations". **On the target tab**, set it on manual Or on Auto mode check as preferred device emulator you want.

You can access the run configurations if you make a right click on your project and then on then "run as" and finally "run configurations..."

Answer (score 1):

It is normal if you have already created an emulator on android 2.3, because Eclipse will install the app on an emulator of the targeted level : 2.3 for your project.
Change you build target to 4.0.3 and I think it will be ok.